# Moving Postgres 10 data dir on Ubuntu 18

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-10

I am trying to move the initial Postgres data dir from

```
/var/lib/postgresql/10/main
```

to another harddrive. The harddrive is accessable within the terminal via

```
/media/chris/Datenspeicher
```

I used [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-change-postgresql-data-folder-location-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide to switch my data dir. Postgres is starting up after modifying the `postgres.conf` file but im not able anymore to access the database through pgadmin or the terminal.

When trying to access the database its asking if the database is running on port 5432 and accepting connections.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
After clean install of ubuntu and postgres all errors still remain.
The postgres log output is:

> 2018-07-06 14:16:04.958 CEST [5664] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
>
> 2018-07-06 14:16:04.998 CEST [5664] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
>
> 2018-07-06 14:16:05.124 CEST [5665] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-07-06 14:00:21 CEST
>
> 2018-07-06 14:16:05.167 CEST [5664] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
>
> 2018-07-06 14:16:05.714 CEST [5672] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: psql: cannot connect to the server: File or Directory not found. Is the server running local and accepting connections on unix-domain-socket >>/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432?

Comment: Did you check the many, many questions with that error message: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+accepting+connections+on+unix-domain-socket

Comment: yes i did. The systemctl status tells me the server is running but the
netstat -na | grep postgres 
prints no answer
I also purged all postgres and reainstalled

Comment: Look in the server log file, probably in /var/log/postgres

Comment: Check the structure and permissions of the copied directory in case you have made some mistake with the `rsync` command. Also you could use a symlink from `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main` to the new data directory instead of reconfiguring the server.

Comment: @jjanes the log says no permission to access the new dir. I used the command:
`sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql /media/christoph/Datenspeicher/` to move the dir

@aventurin when moving with the command from the guide i thought all rights are set correctly. Using `sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /media/christoph/Datenspeicher/postgresql/` and `sudo chmod 700 /media/christoph/Datenspeicher/postgresql/` its not working and resulting in no access rights to the new data dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a clean ubuntu installation (clean all partiotions), auto mounting my second drive and using the answer from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197809/changing-data-directory-for-postgres-on-centos) everything works!

1. installed postgresql-common via:

   `sudo apt install postgresql-common`
2. open createcluster.conf with nano

   `sudo  nano /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf`
3. uncomment line `create_main_cluster = true`
4. change line `data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/%v/%c'` to `new/dir/%v/%c`
5. save file
6. install postgresql via `sudo apt install -y postgresql-10`

Answer (score 2):

Please check the socket file is in the /tmp. If it is there then create a link to /var/run.

OR,
I prefer this method to move the data directory on Ubuntu.

I hope you have the backup copy of the old directory which is in `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main`.

```
service postgresql stop
rm -rf /media/chris/Datenspeicher/*
chown -R postgres:postgres /media/chris/Datenspeicher/
chmod 700 /media/chris/Datenspeicher
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/initdb -D /media/chris/Datenspeicher
rm -rf /media/chris/Datenspeicher/*
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/* /media/chris/Datenspeicher
in postgresql.conf file,  data_directory = '/media/chris/Datenspeicher'
service postgresql start
```

Comment: inside /tmp is no file related to postgres

your provided tasks are sadly not helping either. its resulting in same error message when trying to connect with psql

Comment: Ok, try to find the file `find / -name s.PGSQL.5432` then create the link to `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Comment: sudo find / -name s.PGSQL.5432 -->  find / -name s.PGSQL.5432 no access rights
so the file cannot be found ?

Comment: run this from root user.

Comment: even `su -c 'find / -name s.PGSQL.5432'` didn't help to find the file --> resulted in same message as running with `sudo`

Comment: You don't need the `*` after the trailing slash in the `rsync` command - it won't run with the `*` on Ubuntu 18.04.